# Free/Libre or Open Source PDF editing software for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf, pdf-editor

I am using [Trisquel GNU/Linux](https://trisquel.info) version 7.0 (belenos), based on Ubuntu LTS.

Earlier I had used [**Master PDF Editor**](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php) on Ubuntu, but it is [proprietary software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software). And now on Trisquel GNU/Linux, I’m looking for [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

I've found [**PDFedit**](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html) ([on Free Software Directory](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/PDF_Editor) & [on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/)) and tried it but it is working too slow (sometime hangs and also looking outdated! (not active)).

**Is there any Free/Libre or Open Source PDF editing software which I can use on GNU/Linux** (works like Master PDF Editor or say alternative to it)?

Comment: Good question! in the meanwhile, you might use online PDF editors, such as https://www.pdfescape.com/, https://www.pdfbuddy.com/ or http://www.pdfzorro.com/ . They're not ideal -- speed is unknown, and you're sharing the file with an outside entity.

Comment: Just a comment: PDF is not build to be editable. It's build to look everywhere the same. You should always try to use the originals PDF was created from to edit it. And I know, sometimes it is not possible. But I just wanted to mention this ;)

Comment: See [my answer to "Text annotations and image additions to PDF file using free software"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230940/4671).

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) to convert first the PDF into an ODT file that is of course editable.

If the PDF has not a very sophisticated format the conversion is pretty good.

[image: LibreOffice Draw PDF form edition]

Free, open source.

Warning: The fonts may look different from the original, and capitalization is often off.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there are not that many open source options for PDF editing. However, you might try vector graphics editor [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) - free, open source and multi-platform (including GNU/Linux). However, AFAIK, it doesn't directly support editing existing multi-page PDF documents (seems that it works with single page). Having said that, if you're creating a PDF document from scratch, there is an open source Inkscape plug-in (http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape-pages) that enables multi-page support and PDF export.