# Gratis, Libre, graphical PDF editor for UN*X with specific capabilities

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, pdf, pdf-editor

I want to edit PDFs. Specifically, I want to be able to:

- Add elements to the (intra-page) PDF structure, from as wide a range of whatever constitutes the internal structure of a PDF. Specifically, add text, images, links, interactive elements (like form fields) etc.
- Explore the existing (intra-page) structure of my PDF both in a hierarchical non-rendered view and with highlighting "currently-selected" objects
- Modify parameters and contents of elements in the PDF's structure.
- Change the style/design of a single or of multiple elements.
- Perform batch actions, in general and on-each-page particularly

Requirements:

- When I open a file in the editor, I won't accept it being mangled up in some weird way because it's using a feature my Editor doesn't support.
- Any edits (and of course opening and saving a PDF without edits) to preserve PDF structure, performing minimal changes as necessary - and it's usually not necessary. (so Inkscape is probably not such a great choice).
- Decent Unicode support, including right-to-left languages and right-to-left directions of elements.
- Gratis
- Libre
- Works on Linux
- Works with x86_64 machines

Nice to have:

- Reasonably low memory footprint
- Actively developed
- Multi-platform

Related questions:

- A non-gratis non-libre solution: [PDF editor for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35900/15631)
- A free editor but without my feature requirement: [Free/Libre or Open Source PDF editing software for GNU/Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17567/free-libre-or-open-source-pdf-editing-software-for-gnu-linux)

Comment: PDFedit probably comes closest, although I don't know if it meets all your requirements.

Comment: Another related question: [A PDF editor for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/a-pdf-editor-for-linux)

Comment: Duplicate, or very nearly so: [Free/Libre or Open Source PDF editing software for GNU/Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17567/free-libre-or-open-source-pdf-editing-software-for-gnu-linux)

Comment: @JohnY: I have multiple requirements which the other question does not. And LibreOffice doesn't begin to meet them. But I will make that clear with an edit.

Comment: Fair enough. I find it difficult to tell what the boundary is between "duplicate" and "related". Especially when the same software can be a good solution for multiple not-identical questions. (Or in the case of LibreOffice, an equally poor solution to a whole bunch of not-identical questions. ;) Ultimately, I'm just trying to give exposure to suggestions which might be helpful for other people stumbling upon your question, so calling it "related" serves the purpose.

Comment: @JohnY: See [this](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89471). Perhaps the worst outstanding right-to-left language support bug in all of LibreOffice...